# Atualizar a página quando fechar popup

Tags: javascript, html

Como poderei atualizar uma página após fechar um popup? Após o utilizador abrir o popup, eu dou uma serie de opções que alteram a página onde o utilizador abriu o popup e preciso dessa página atualizada apos o utilizador fechar o popup.
Como poderei fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `Location.reload()` recarrega o documento:

```
location.reload();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 1):

Em javascript há a boa e velha função *reload*:

```
location.reload();
```

E tem a vantagem de funcionar nos principais *browsers*. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizei assim:

```
//principal.htm
<body onunload="window.opener.location.reload();">

//popup.htm
<script>opener.location.reload(); window.close();</script>
```

Comment: David explica mais a sua solução, assim você ajuda mais as pessoas.